# cURL bypassing same origin policy

Tags: javascript, php, curl

So I am writing a script for cURL, and the script emulates my browser in everywhere way. But I am still getting a session is invalid error. I was looking through the chrome console and saw two errors saying

"SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "`http://localhost`" from accessing a frame with origin "http://edugen.wileyplus.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match"

"Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://edugen.wileyplus.com" from accessing a frame with origin "`http://localhost`". Protocols, domains, and ports must match"

I looked up this error and I got some information on how it has to do with chrome no longer allowing frames or something, but I doubt it's that because the console references these two lines of code.

```
var win = self;
    while ( typeof(win.isLTIRoot) == 'undefined' && win.parent != null && win.parent != self && win.parent != win )
```

and this one

```
function setSTNOnLoadListener(wnd) {
    setSTNFrameOnLoadListener(wnd, wnd.document.getElementsByTagName('frame'));
    setSTNFrameOnLoadListener(wnd, wnd.document.getElementsByTagName('iframe'));
}
```

So what strategy should I use with cURL and what exactly is the problem.

Edit: More detail and curl code

So I am trying to log into a website and get to the mainframe. The whole process is tedious as I have to follow 9 location headers and everything goes fine but when I finally reach the webpage i get the error "your session is invalid".

here is the curl code for the last page for the mainframe.

```
$ch = curl_init();

// Set some options - we are passing in a useragent too here
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => FALSE,  // Setting cURL to follow 'location' HTTP headers
    CURLOPT_URL => $url9,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0",
    CURLOPT_STDERR => $verbose = fopen('php://temp', 'rw+'),
    CURLOPT_VERBOSE => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                                'Host: edugen.wileyplus.com',
                                'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
                                'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5'
                            ),
    CURLOPT_CAINFO => dirname(__FILE__)."\cacert.pem",
    CURLOPT_HEADER => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => $ckfile,
    CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => $ckfile
));
 if( ! $tenth_page = curl_exec($ch)) 
            { 
                trigger_error(curl_error($ch)); 
            } 
$urlEndpoint = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
echo "Verbose information:\n<pre>", !rewind($verbose), htmlspecialchars(stream_get_contents($verbose)), "</pre>\n";

curl_close($ch);

$tenth_page = str_replace("src=\"","src=\"http://edugen.wileyplus.com",$tenth_page);

echo $tenth_page;
```

Comment: what does the js window security error have to do with curl?

Comment: the curl "iFrame" is localhost and websites "iFrame" is wileyplus. I put iFrame in quotes because I'm still not sure what it is.

Comment: show us the curl code, and explain what you're trying to do better.

Answer (score 0):

I expect they have deployed some security to prevent their page being loaded within an iFrame from a different domain.

The other common mistake when developing is when your dev site is referenced as localhost - if you are making ajax calls then you should ensure you alias your dev site to be the same domain as the sites you are calling if they have any cross origin security set.

Comment: yes my dev site is called localhost, iFrame is there a way to trick it into thinking the iFrame is the same?

Comment: Sometimes you can get away with making it a subdomain of the host you are accessing e.g. local.other.hostname. - You will need to correct your dns or edit your hosts file so that it resolves to 127.0.0.1

Comment: wow, change the host? There's no http header or curl function to change it? What is an i Frame?

Comment: No change the host name of your dev web server - for a linux / osx box you can do it via editing /etc/hosts  - then you can access your site on the same domain as the site you are querying.   There is no point in doing this if you do not have an agreement in place for when you go live!  

It may be best to reach out to them and explain what you are trying to do and see if they will update their access policy.

Comment: I don't think their going to update their policy, especially if I explain what I am doing. This is like a greyhat sort of thing.